# Space is not shown

Tags: c++, space

Hello so i have a problem with the spaces in c++ check this

```
char inp[10000];
char outp[10000];
int i;
cin >> inp;
for(i=0;i<=strlen(inp);i++)
{
  outp [i] = inp[i];
  cout << outp[i];
}
```

So if i run this and type: Hello stackoverflow the output will be: Hello.
Any help will be appreciated , also this is just a part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cin>>` just takes the word until it encounters \0

**`cin.getline(name of string, string size)`  takes the words until it encounters \n**

**`\0`** - Null character, it is there in every string of continues letters.
**`\n`** - New line character, it is there when a line ends, (a line consists generally of 80 characters).

So, in your code you have used `cin>>` which makes your program to only take a single word and not more than that. 
 **Try using `cin.getline(name of string, size of string)` instead which will make your code work accordingly.**

Comment: Okay im kinda new to c++ and coding in general and this cleared some things out for me , thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

`std::cout` separate words by white spaces (normally), you can use `std::getline` instead.

```
std::getline(std::cin, inp);
```

And, it's better to use `std::string` for strings rather that array of characters.

Comment: Iam checking for some specific chars inside for but unfortunatly i can't post the entire code right now

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why are you using arrays of chars instead of `std::string`? Much cleaner to use strings unless you have a VERY good reason for using arrays of chars.  Secondly, if you want to read in a variable amount of words and save each of them individually (which it seems like you might be trying to do), try this:

```
std::string output[10000];
std::string inp;
int i = 0;
while (cin >> inp){
   output[i] = inp;
   i++;
}
```

This will read all your words and store each one in a separate index in `output`.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `>>` operator of `cin`, it takes the first token of a string separated by spaces. Hence, saying:

```
cin >> input; // where input is "hello 12 years"
```

... is exactly the same with

```
std::getline( cin, input, ` `);
```

To get the entire "sentence" that the user enters in the console, you have to use `std::getline` without the `separator` parameter:

```
std::getline( cin, input );
```